# What does "a class instantiates another" mean?

Tags: design-patterns, gang-of-four

From Design Pattern by GoF:

> Another  useful  thing  to  show  is **which  classes instantiate
>   which  others**.  We use a dashed arrowheaded line to indicate this,
>   since OMT doesn't support it. We call this the  "creates"
>   relationship.  The arrow points to the class that's instantiated. In
>   Figure B.lc, CreationTool creates LineShape objects.
>
> [image]

What does "a class instantiates another" mean here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to phrase it would be "a class creates an instance of another", which makes it a little more obvious.

It just means that `Class A` creates an instance of `Class B` inside of it (or "`Class A` instantiates `Class B`").

For example, you might have a `Person` class, which creates an instance of a `Hand` class, which it then uses.

Comment: Thanks. Is composition the only case when a class creates instance of another?

Comment: Not really. Many patterns could involve creating an instance of another class for some reason. For example, the Dependency Injection pattern instantiates dependent classes, and then injects them into other classes to for those classes to use.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you could also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479898/how-is-instantiation-different-from-aggregation-and-from-acquaintance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478884/how-is-instantiation-different-from-aggregation-and-from-acquaintance,  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478736/can-more-than-one-objects-aggregate-the-same-object