# Can more than one objects aggregate or acquaint or instantiate the same object?

Tags: design-patterns, aggregation

Design Pattern by Gamma et al said

> Consider the distinction between object aggregation and acquaintance and how differently they manifest themselves at compile- and run-times.
>
> Aggregation implies that one object owns or is responsible for another object. Generally we speak of an object having or being part of another object. Aggregation implies that an aggregate object and its owner have identical lifetimes.
>
> Acquaintance implies that an  object  merely knows  of another object. Sometimes acquaintance is called "association" or the "using" relationship. Acquainted objects may request operations  of each other, but they aren't responsible for each other. Acquaintance is a weaker relationship than aggregation and  suggests much looser coupling
>   between objects.
>
> Another  useful  thing  to  show  is which  classes instantiate which  others.    We call this the
>   "creates" relationship.  The arrow points to the class that's instantiated. In Figure c,
>
> [image]

Can more than one objects aggregate the same object?
If object A aggregate object B, can another object say C also aggregate B?

Can more than one objects acquaint the same object?
If object A acquaint object B, can another object say C also acquaint B?

Can more than one objects   instantiate the same object?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding and the common definitions I know, *Composition* is an association where the lifetime of the associated objects is tied to the lifetime of the owner. *Aggregation* describes an association where the lifetime of the aggregated objects is independent from the lifetime of the owner. *Acquaintance* is the same as *association*.

According to this definition an object can be aggregated by multiple owners in an *aggregate* association. If the association is of type *composition* then sharing is by definition not intended.

*Association* or *acquaintance* are more generic description of a relationship between objects. So it depends on the details of the relationship if a single object can have multiple owners. But when being that generic, it is generally possible.

[Wikipedia Object composition and aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

But I think there exists another definition which was introduced by Martin Fowler. It's the one you were quoting. To me this is the less known definition since the one that I rendered is defined in the UML rules which are widely spread and have become a de facto standard. According to M. Fowler's definition *aggregation* is equal to *composition* whereas *acquaintance* matches the UML definition of *aggregation*.

So the answer to your questions is, when looking through the eyes of M. Fowler: the rules for *composition* apply when talking about Fowler's *aggregation* which means multiple owners can't aggregate the same objects **and** in terms of *acquaintance* the rules of the in the UML defined *aggregation* association apply meaning that multiple owners can acquaint the same objects independently (from their lifetime).0

And of course you can create instances of an object as often as you want or as memory is available and where you want. The object or the class is only the definition whereas the instance (as a result of the instantiation) is the actual allocated memory area to store data of the object (e.g. fields). The class definition describes the layout of this allocated memory area.

Comment: Thanks. How about "Another useful thing to show is which classes instantiate which others. We call this the 'creates' relationship."?  Can more than one objects  instantiate the same object?

Comment: So the answer is yes, when object A and object B and object C are each creating an instance of object X. But this instances of object X are  never the same when looking at their memory locations.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate if you could also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479898/how-is-instantiation-different-from-aggregation-and-from-acquaintance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478884/how-is-instantiation-different-from-aggregation-and-from-acquaintance

Comment: Instantiation creates an object instance while aggregation describes the relationship between objects (that are already created or instantiated)

Comment: "When object A instantiates/aggrgate/acquaint object B, must object A have a field member referencing object B?"  YES

Comment: When object A instantiates object B, must object A have a field member referencing object B, or object A's method creates and returns object B? (Could you reply the two questions at their links)

Comment: Thanks for replying in the other links. I'd appreciate if you could also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482491/what-is-the-creates-instantiation-relationship-like-between-two-classes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483736/does-factory-method-pattern-follow-template-pattern-and-abstract-factory-patter

Comment: I already explained the 'creates instance' relationship in the other question. I even provide code examples.

Comment: The last paragraph also anwsers the question regarding the fields. [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478884/when-object-a-instantiates-aggrgate-acquaint-object-b-must-object-a-have-a-fiel/56485674#56485674)