# What is the "creates"/instantiation relationship like between two classes?

Tags: design-patterns

From Design Patterns by Gamma et al

> An object reference representing  a part-of or aggregation  relationship  is
>   indicated by an arrowheaded  line with a diamond  at the base. The arrow points to
>   the class that is **aggregated**  (e.g., Shape).
>
> An arrowheaded  line without  the  diamond
>   denotes **acquaintance** (e.g., a LineShape keeps a reference to a Color object, which other
>   shapes may share). A name for the reference may appear near the base to  distinguish
>   it from other references
>
> Another  useful  thing  to  show  is which  classes **instantiate**
>   which  others.  We use a dashed arrowheaded line to indicate this,
>   since OMT doesn't support it. We call this the  "creates"
>   relationship.  The arrow points to the class that's instantiated. In
>   Figure c, CreationTool creates LineShape objects.
>
> [image]

I would like to understand what the book means by the "creates" relationship.

When class A instantiates class B, must class A have a field member referencing an object B, or must class A have a  method which creates and returns object B?

Is there some design pattern (for example, described in the same book) which makes use of the "creates"/instantiation relationship?  I couldn't find it.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly are you asking for... patterns that create instances [creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) or example of some other pattern that also uses creational pattern?

Comment: My question asks what the book means by "creates" relationship.

Comment: Isn't that obvious? "CreationTool creates LineShape objects" It means that instance of class CreationTool is responsible for creating (instantiating) instances of class LineShape.

Comment: Not as obvious as code. For example, when class A instantiates class B, must class A have a field member referencing an object B, or must class A have a  method which creates and returns object B? If the book shows a design pattern which uses the "creates" relationship, it may be more obvious.

Comment: There are all kinds of variations of "when class A instantiates class B" so specific patterns and usage will depend on situation. If you are talking about design patterns then there is always method involved, but generally creates relationship can also include plain class that constructs its field member directly. Creates relationship does not specify ownership - so fields are completely optional. Again, take a look at creational patterns.

Answer (score 1):

*A creates B* simply means the code inside A directly creates instances of B -- by using the `new` keyword. The code can be in the constructors or any methods of A or anywhere inside A.

The reason this kind of relationship is concerned is that it is a *strong* relationship, i.e., it causes tight-coupling between classes. When class A directly creates instances of class B, we cannot reuse A in another context where we want A to create instances of a child class of B, without modifying source code of A.

To have such a flexibility, we often use the Factory Method pattern or the Abstract Factory pattern. In these patterns, the task of directly creating instances belong to a child class of A (Factory Method) or a concrete factory class (Abstract Factory).

Comment: I think a more modern answer is that to have flexibility, we often use Dependency Injection. Factory patterns are a bit primitive and outdated, IMO.